# ssis dataflow buffer

Tags: ssis

I know that SQL server use memory cache for the all operations by loading data from hard disk to RAM when ever we select or update or etc.Also,I have read like SSIS also use some buffer for data flow task.So, my questions are..

1)Whether these buffer and cache are same?

2)If yes,We used to write sql statment inside the data flow task(eg:OLEDB Data Source task) so SSIS has to create some buffer for loading data.Whether the executed sql statment inside the OLEDB Source task will not create any cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not the same.

The SQL Server database engine has its own cache and each SSIS Data Flow Task in a package that is running has its own cache as well.

So, when you have a SQL Server query in a OLEDB Data Source Task, inside a Data Flow Task, in a running SSIS package, the SQL Server has to bring all the data to the database engine cache, and the data is then read into a buffer of the Data Flow Task (which may then pass through various buffers along the dataflow pipeline).

Memory usage by the SQL Server database engine and SSIS packages are huge topics by themselves, but I hope this answers your question.